# JPQL query returning List of objects with "null-valued" fields

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have in a repository interface the following query :

```
 @Query("SELECT DISTINCT prb FROM Problem prb
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT act FROM Action act WHERE act.problem = prb AND act.dismissed IS FALSE"))
```

It is supposed to retrieve the list of **problems** that have at least one   **action** not **dismissed**.
It does return a list of problems, the list size is correct, but all the fields values are **null** as you can see below (so I can't judge if the items are what have to be returned):

```
[
  {
    "prbId": null,
    "description": null,
    "domaine": null,
    "who": null,
    "what": null,
    "when": null,
    "where": null,
    "action": null,
    "zone": null
  }
]
```

I am using **PostgresSQL**, and here are my Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Problem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "prb_id")
    private long prbId;
    private String description;
    private String domaine;
    private String who;
    private String what;
    private String where;
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDateTime when;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "problem", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PlanAction> plansAction = new ArrayList<>();
   
    // constrctor, getters and setters ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "actions")
public class Action implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long actId;

    private String description;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDate dueDate;

    private String status;

    private boolean dismissed;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "problem_id")
    private Problem problem;

    // constructors, getters anf setters
}
```

could any explains why this happens, and how to make the list elements appear with their values
not null.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like prbId is the primary key, I think `DISTINCT` can be removed

Comment: Hi, @indybee . Yes the "prbId" is the primary key.  If I remove ```DISTINCT``` I would have duplications.